# Pivot Table - How to use Calculated Item to calculate the growth rate of a Calculated Field

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Here is a sample of the raw data of my Pivot Table:
[raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1SoJ.jpg)

Beyond the  "Kg" and "Sales", I also created another metric "$/Kg" by using the Calculated Field ($/Kg = Sales / Kg). I am trying to show the YoY growth in Pivot Table by using Calculated Item (Growth % = '2019'/'2018' - 1) , however I can't get the correct result of the "$/Kg".

As shown in the [Pivot Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHzfO.jpg), the growth rate of the $/Kg is 374% instead of 27%. Can any one point me a direction of fixing it? Thank you!